# Bash Script to Rename Files In Subdirectory - Based on file name

Tags: linux, bash

I currently have some IP camera images on an FTP. They come in from the camera with the format 192.168.1.50_01_20170308114736213_TIMING.jpg for example.

Im looking for a batch script to rename these files to the camera name followed by the time and date of the image in DD/MM/YYYY_HHMM - can anyone offer any advise how I swould go about this??
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a method to make an IP correspond to a camera name ? Also, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: `/` is not a valid character in file name so you'll have to change to so other delimiter

Comment: I actually found a script online to try and help - although I dont really understand it - it tries to get exif info - see here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2328946 - as there is no exif info thats getting the file down to  format like 20170308 104742

Comment: Also while I can specifiy a folder sub directory on the ftp I can specify the camera name in the file string of the image

Answer (score 0):

This is my script, as argument u use path to directory wtih jpg files

> ex. ./script.sh /home/user/cam_photos

```
#!/bin/bash

directory=$1
temp_file=temp.txt
new_file=new.txt
filter2_out=filter2_out.txt
filter3_out=filter3_out.txt
name_out=out.txt
old_names=old.txt
new_names=new_names.txt
command_to_do=command.txt

function ReadFilenames()
{
cd $directory
ls -1 > $old_names
ls -1 | sed 's/^[^_]*_//' | sed 's/^[^_]*_//' | sed 's/_TIMING//' > $temp_file
}

function Filter_1()
{
awk -v clist='4 6 8 12' '
BEGIN { n = split(clist, cl, / /)
}
{       for(i = n; i; i--)
                $0 = substr($0, 1, cl[i]) " " substr($0, cl[i] + 1)
        print
}' $temp_file > $new_file
}

function Filter_2()
{
awk '{print $3,$2,$1,$4}' $new_file > $filter2_out
}

function Filter_3()
{
sed 's/ /_/g; s/$/.jpg/' $filter2_out > $filter3_out
}

function NameOutput()
{
sed 's/$/.jpg/' $filter3_out > $name_out
}

function Make_command()
{
sed 's/^/mv /' $old_names > $new_names
sleep 1
paste -d' ' $new_names $filter3_out > $command_to_do
}

function Run()
{
bash $command_to_do
}

function Clear()
{
rm $temp_file $new_file $filter2_out $filter3_out $name_out $old_names $new_names $command_to_do
}

ReadFilenames
Filter_1
Filter_2
Filter_3
NameOutput
Make_command
Run
Clear
```

Yours names:

```
192.168.1.50_01_20170308114236213_TIMING.jpg
192.168.1.50_01_20170308114336213_TIMING.jpg
192.168.1.50_01_20170308114436213_TIMING.jpg
192.168.1.50_01_20170308114536213_TIMING.jpg
192.168.1.50_01_20170308114636213_TIMING.jpg
192.168.1.50_01_20170308114736213_TIMING.jpg
```

OUTPUT:

```
08_03_2017_1142.jpg
08_03_2017_1143.jpg
08_03_2017_1144.jpg
08_03_2017_1145.jpg
08_03_2017_1146.jpg
08_03_2017_1147.jpg
```